# jQuery buttons fade in sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of numbered buttons that I want to fade in one by one. I'm just not sure exactly how to approach this.

```
var animations = new Array();
// queue all
$(".owl-thumb-item").each(function() {
  animations.push($(this));
});

// start animating
doAnimation(animations.shift());

function doAnimation(image) {
  image.fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // wait until animation is done and recurse if there are more animations
    if (animations.length > 0) doAnimation(animations.shift());
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dng53ekp/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All buttons need to be hidden initially. Use `display: none` css property.

```
button {
    display: none;
}
```

Your `js` is working fine.

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dng53ekp/1/)